# Is it possible to disable write ahead logging in NTFS?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, ntfs, azure

In my Azure roles I don't really care of what happens if the virtual machine crashes - I'll get a new one with completely reset and intact disks if that happens. So to me NTFS write-ahead logging that ensures that the filesystem remains intact is just waste of time.

Can I disable write-ahead logging in NTFS?

Answer (score 0):

No, not that I'm aware of.  NTFS' behaviour can be modified in a limited sense using **fsutil behavior**.